# How to delete records after archiving?

Tags: sql, oracle

Am archiving last 4 to 12 months of data. Below query does the job.

```
insert into process_state_archive
  select *
    from process_state
   where tstamp BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), -12) AND
         LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') - 4);
```

Now I want to delete 4 to 12 months data in process_state table. Where to add this condition in the above query? Can anyone please tell me?

Comment: Why can't you add another command for deleting the records ? `delete process_state where 
tstamp BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE,'MONTH'), -12) AND LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE,  'MONTH') - 4)`

Comment: Thank you. And also is there any way to check the no.of records which are being archived and no.of records being deleted after archiving? So that, If both counts are matching then Commit will be performed.

Answer (score 2):

Here it goes (not tested)

```
DECLARE
  v_insert_count number;
  v_delete_count number;
BEGIN
  insert into process_state_archive 
  select * 
    from process_state 
    where tstamp BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE,'MONTH'), -12) AND LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE,  'MONTH') - 4);

  v_insert_count := sql%rowcount;

  delete process_state 
   where  tstamp BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE,'MONTH'), -12) AND LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE,  'MONTH') - 4);

  v_delete_count := sql%rowcount;

  if v_insert_count = v_delete_count then
    commit;
  else
    rollback;
  end if;

END;
/
```

`sql%rowcount` returns count of rows effected by the last sql statement.